# What benefits do I get from sneak attacking a knocked out enemy with two-fisted shooter?

Tags: dnd-4e, rogue

After having successfully knocked out a target, I use [Coup de grace](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=325)<sup>1</sup> with Sly Flourish on the target. I hit, and automatically critical.

How much damage do I do?

I have the [two-fisted shooter](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=826) feat. How does that interact with the critical I just achieved?

<sup>1</sup>You automatically score a critical hit when you deal a coup de grace (page 288) and KO'ed Targets get -5 to all defenses

Answer (score 5):

OK. You've got an unconscious critter on your hands. That also makes him prone.

So for Sly Flourish you'll get critical damage (weapon die and sneak attack both maxed, and your critical dice if your weapon provides them).

You also, because you have scored a critical hit, get to use your Two-Fisted Shooter feat. However, there is a catch:

If you used the Rogue power Knockout, you've already woken the creature up when you hit it with Sly Flourish and you do not qualify for a coup de grâce a second time. If the creature is sleeping the same is true; when they take damage they wake up.